# r - Update rows in excel using values from a dataframe

Tags: r, excel

My objective is to update specific rows in an excel sheet from rows from a dataframe in R.

For example there is an excel sheet containing the below mentioned records

Car     Year  Mileage
Mazda   2020   40000
Rav4    2017   35000
Civic   2021   25000

I read this excel file into R dataframe. I perform a simple calculation which should display rows of data where mileage is greater than 30000. So the df output looks like this.

df
Car     Year  Mileage
Mazda   2020   40000
Rav4    2017   35000

My question here is, if there is a way to highlight only these columns back to the excel sheet?

Comment: My objective is to just highlight these two rows in excel sheet with any color (red or yellow) or even append a new column in the same excel sheet adjacent to mileage with something like status with values as good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458754/how-to-highlight-excel-cells-in-r

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight an Excel row with the following code. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\test_File_1.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 

obj_Entire_Row <- Sheets[[1]]$Rows(1)$EntireRow()$Interior()
obj_Entire_Row[["ColorIndex"]] <- 8 # Color entire row
```

To insert a new column, you can consider the following approach.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\test_File_1.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 
Sheets[[1]]$Range("B1")$EntireColumn()$Insert()
```